# Enide Studio (Nodeclipse) - Can't debug project as NPM package on OS X Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, node.js, npm, nodeclipse, enide

I've set up a new project in Enide Studio. (Which's an Eclipse with Node.js plugins.)
I right-click the project and choose "Debug As -> Debug Cofigurations...".
In the popup window I double-click "NPM" configuration, and type "start" to the Goal textbox.
Then click to "Debug" and get the following error in the console:

```
"execvp(): No such file or directory"
```

When I run "npm start" from command line, it works fine.
If it matters, my operating system is OS X 10.9.

Have anyone faced with the same problem? What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on .js file and then "Debug As -> Node application"

With Node any .js file can be executed. (Hint: this also give you one more way to validate.)

Other debug options were not yet implemented or tested (as ChromeDevTools can give more options, we just have not tried everything, but implemented the most straight-forward ). Play with what you can, raise an issue on github with the error / feature description. https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues

Be sure that you have read http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support and Online / built-in Help Debug page.